# Smooth shading in three.js from blender

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I have a scene in Blender that renders smoothly but when brought into a three.js scene the curved faces are flat. Is there a way to make these curved sides smooth as shown below?

I have calculated vertex normals and set the smoothShaded flag, neither changes the appearance. I've tried lambert, phong, and standard materials.

Desired look:

[image]

In threejs. scene:

[image]

Edit: I've tried the following:

```
this.traverse(function(child) {
    if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
    {
         child.material.smoothShading = true;
    }
});

this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
this.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Comment: What loader are you using in order to import your model?

Comment: @Mugen87 I am importing an OBJ using the editor at https://threejs.org/editor/

Comment: Can you please try it with `glTF`? It's the recommended 3D format of `three.js`. You can find all relevant information in this [guide](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models). Use this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html) as a code template. You should actually not use `OBJ` anymore since it's in many ways worse than `glTF`(bigger file sizes, longer parsing times, no animation support etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I am now using the glTF exporter! My problem was in Blender after all. Solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in Blender. I needed to smooth the faces of rounded extrusions and set hard edges on the corners in the Shading panel.

[image]

[image]